# Creating an ORC file and not Hive table?

Tags: hadoop, hive

From what I googled around and found are ways of creating an ORC table using Hive but I want a an ORC file on which I can run my custom map-reduce job.

Also please let me know that the file created by Hive under the warehouse directory for my ORC table is a table file of ORC and not an actutal ORC file I can use? like: `/user/hive/warehouse/tbl_orc/000000_0`

Comment: Assuming your Hive table is defined as ORC and located in that directory -- when you run a SELECT, Hive will process each file in that directory *(possibly with different mappers)* with the ORC SerDe. And when you run an INSERT-SELECT, then each Hive reducer *(or each mapper in case there is no need for reducing)* will create a new file in that directory, using ORC SerDe.

Comment: Bottom line: a table is mapped on a **directory**, not on a file. Any program -- Hive, Pig, MapReduce, Spark -- can add file(s) in that directory, as long as they use the correct structure. And that structure is defined in the Hive Metastore, which is accessible via **HCatalog**.

Comment: ok, so from what I understand here is that when I did an insert from a non orc table into my orc table it created this file under the above directory and this is an actual ORC file, which I can use in my custom mapreduce program?

Comment: when you mention custom map reduce program, are you intending to use hive for the map reduce job or java map reduce?. Because an ORC file is in a compressed format and can only be read by Hive. And as Samson mentioned above, you cannot read a single file. You have to read the directory with all the ORC files as table to access the data.

Comment: @dheee I was talking about java mapreduce program. And I disagree when you say that ORC file can only be read using Hive as I can directly read it via my java MapReduce program.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Please correct me if I am wrong in the above statement.

Comment: In theory, if you use the ORC SerDe in your custom MapReduce job, then you can read the file(s) -- just like a Hive MapReduce job would, and just like a Pig+HCatalog MapReduce job would. In practice, there is a lot of boilerplate code and config to set correctly. So Pig might be more practical than Java...

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Thanks for clearing my doubts. If you want to post these as you answer I will accept that and close this question. Or please let me know how to proceed on this as I have got the required info on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Wrap-up of the discussion]*

- a Hive table is mapped on a HDFS directory *(or a list of
  directories, if the table is partitioned)*
- all files in that directory use the same SerDe (ORC, Parquet, AVRO,
  Text, etc.) and have the same column set; all together, they contain all the data available for that table
- each file in that directory is the result of a previous MapReduce job
  -- either a Hive INSERT, a Pig dataset saved via HCatalog, a Spark dataset saved via HiveContext... or any custom job that happens to
  drop a file there, hopefully compliant with the table SerDe and
  schema *(retrieved via MetastoreClient Java API, or via HCatalog API,
  whatever)*
- note that a single job with 3 reducers will probably create 3 new
  files (and maybe 1 empty file + 1 small file + 1 big file!); and a
  job with 24 mappers and no reducer will create 24 files, unless some
  kind of "merge small files" post-processing step is enabled
- note also that most file names give absolutely no information about
  the way the file is encoded intenally, they are just sequence numbers
  (i.e. the 5th job to add 12 files will typically create files `000004_0` to
  `000004_11`)

All in all, processing an ORC fileset with a Java MapReduce program **should** be very similar to processing a Text fileset. You just have to provide the correct SerDe and the correct field mapping -- I think that the encryption algorithm is explicit in the files so the Serde handles it auto-magically at read time. Just remember that ORC files are not splittable at record level, but at stripe level *(a stripe is a bunch of record stored in columnar format w/ tokenization and optional compression)*.

Of course, that will not give you access to ORC advanced features such a vectorization or stripe pruning *(somewhat similar to "smart scan" in Oracle Exadata)*.

Comment: Very well explained. Thanks